# Question about mclaurin series in complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

Use the following representation to write $sin(z^2)$ as a mclaurin series

$$sin(z)= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n \frac{z^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!} \text{  }(|z|<\infty)$$

and point out how it follows that $f^{4n}(0)=0$ and $f^{2n+1}(0)=0$ $(n=0,1,2,..)$

Approach: $$sin(z^2)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n \frac{z^{4n+2}}{(2n+1)!} \text{  }|z|< \infty$$

For the second part, I am basically writing the string of the power series representation and see  where $a_n=0$. Since $a_n=\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}$, the only way $a_n$ is 0 is if $f^{n}(0)$ is 0, so in the power representation  I can see that $a_{4n}$ and $a_{2n+1}$ do not exist. I don't know if that's an answer.

Comment: For the second part, essentially you are right. Realize that $4n+2$ can never be a multiple of $4n$ and also $4n+2$ is even, $2n+1$ is odd, so...

Comment: @imranfat Hi imranfat, I would like to have a private conversation with you because based on the description of your intro page, I am just like you. I did very bad in math at high school, but now I am studying it. I am getting A's in most of my courses. I know it doesn't reflect I am good at something, but at least I am a little better. I chose math because uhhhh

Comment: It's quite late over here, but yes, I was a mediocre student in High school with B's and C's for math, who happened to get an unexpectedly very high grade for the final math exam. That prompted me to think that perhaps math wasn't that bad of a choice for me...And so it happened...Got more time on Monday to discuss...